# How to notify a user that a message has been sent othem even if they don't have a SignalR connection id?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I've been struggling with implementing a private one-on-one chat similar to Facebook's Messenger in my .NET Core 7 web app. Over the past week, I've made progress on it. Currently, when a user, let's call them User A, clicks on a button labeled 'chat', they connect to my chat hub and receive a connection ID. This allows User B to send messages to User A successfully.

However, I've encountered a problem. If User A hasn't opened a chat before, they won't have connected to the SignalR hub and won't possess a connection ID. Consequently, they won't receive real-time notifications when a message is sent to them.

I'm finding it challenging to find a solution for this problem. I haven't come across any related questions on StackOverflow either. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain a valid approach to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea for your situation. SignalR will not remain the message, If User A is not in the current chat room when User B sends a message to him, The message will be lost when User A enters the chat room again. for unread messages, you can store/persist those messages in somewhere, and if you want to persist information after restarts or you would host hub on multi-servers/instances, in-memory store is not a good approach. You can try to store messages in database etc permanent, external storage. When User A haven't connected to SignalR Hub but User B send message to him, Save these messages into database, Once the project detect there are some unread saved in database, Use WebSocket to show a notification in some place(Just like the Red dot on recent inbox messages in stackoverflow),Once User A click this notification, redirect to chart room ,recover message from database.